# Can $\ln|\cos x|$ be written as $-\ln|\sec x|$? absolute function

Tags: logarithms

$\ln|\cos x| = \ln|1/\sec x| = \ln|(\sec x)^{-1}|=-\ln|\sec x|$

Is what I am doing valid? Or is it not correct because of the absolute function?

Comment: I don't think $\log\lvert \cos x \rvert = \log \lvert \tan x \rvert$

Comment: I edited the question, sorry... was suppose to be sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you are doing is wrong because $\cot x=\frac{1}{\tan x}$.

But I would like to point out that $$\ln |\cos x|=-\ln |\sec x|$$
Is true, as $|a||\frac{1}{a}|=1$ is always true. The absolute function does not hinder it one bit. (well, it does as it makes it both positive. but it does not effect the multiple).

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. Suppose $\ln|\cos x|=-\ln|\cot x|$; the expression makes sense only if $\cos x\ne0$, $\cot x\ne0$ and $\cot x$ is defined, so for $x\ne k\pi/2$ (for $k$ an integer).

Then the equality is equivalent to
$$
|\cos x|=\frac{1}{|\cot x|},\qquad x\ne k\pi/2
$$
that is, to
$$
|\cos x|(|\sin x|-1)=0,\qquad x\ne k\pi/2
$$
No $x$ satisfies these conditions.